# Append to subject line when auto-forwarding ExchangeService emails

Tags: asp.net, exchange-server

I have a script which sets up rules on users' outlooks which autoforward their emails to marked recipients, should they be out of the office.

I wish to alter the subject before sending, ideally prefixing it with "AUTFORWARD: The subject".

I cannot see how to do this, if it is possible at all.

```
Dim oRule As New Rule()
oRule.DisplayName = "Forwarder"
oRule.Actions.ForwardToRecipients.Add("me@address.com")
Dim oCreateNewRule As New CreateRuleOperation(oRule)
oExchangeService.UpdateInboxRules(New RuleOperation() {oCreateNewRule}, True)
oCreateNewRule = Nothing
oRule = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Action in EWS that will allow you to set the subject with a Rule (or any property other then the importance or categories). You could look at using a Transport Rule instead which allows a lot more Actions http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998315(v=exchg.150).aspx. Eg one thing you can do with a Transport Rule is detect if a message is AutoForwarded using the conditions and then use the  prepend subject action to achieve what you want. The only problem with this is it would affect all users who are forwarding messages which may or may not be a problem. Other then that you could write a Transport Agent which would give you full flexibility.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Ah, yes we use hosted exchange which (I believe) does not support this method.

Comment: If your using hosted Exchange Transport Agents are out some hosters do allow transport Rules (eg Exchange Online allows Transport Rules). One other option is to write your own auto-responder using EWS Streaming notifications